# Unable to connect to the remote server at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I'm able to FTP to the server and upload files while running VS2013 in Debug, but when I compile as Release | x86 I get the error "Unable to connect to the remote server" at the line that calls System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(). 
I can get to the FTP and upload files using WinSCP. I've run WireShark and seen no packets at all from the Release version of my code but saw all relevant packets when I executed from Debug mode within VS2013. I've got no firewall and it's really got me stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated. - Chuck

```
    public bool UploadToFtp(string sFtpServer, string sFtpUserName, string sFtpPassword, string sSourceLocationPath, string sFtpDestinationPath, StringBuilder sbLogMessage)
    {
        bool bUpload;
        try
        {
            var oFile = new FileInfo(sSourceLocationPath);
            var oUri = new Uri(sFtpServer + sFtpDestinationPath + oFile.Name);
            var oFtp = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(oUri);
            oFtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(sFtpUserName, sFtpPassword);
            oFtp.KeepAlive = false;
            oFtp.UseBinary = true;
            oFtp.UsePassive = true;
            oFtp.Timeout = 10000000;
            oFtp.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000000;
            oFtp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            oFtp.ContentLength = oFile.Length;
            var arrContent = File.ReadAllBytes(oFile.FullName);
            using (var oFileStream = oFile.OpenRead())
            {
                using (var oStream = oFtp.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    int iReadBytes;
                    do
                    {
                        iReadBytes = oFileStream.Read(arrContent, 0, int.Parse(oFile.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
                        oStream.Write(arrContent, 0, iReadBytes);
                    } while (iReadBytes != 0);

                    bUpload = true;
                    oStream.Flush();
                    oStream.Close();
                    oFileStream.Close();
                }
            }
            File.Delete(sSourceLocationPath + oFile.Name);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogMessage(ex.Message);
            bUpload = false;
        }
        return bUpload;
    }
```

***** EDIT *****
I created a network trace log as suggested and got the following output (NOTE: I have changed the actual IP # and filename in this listing):

```
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [27252] WebRequest::Create(ftp://1.2.3.4//file.zip)
System.Net Information: 0 : [27252] FtpWebRequest#28316044::.ctor(ftp://1.2.3.4//file.zip)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [27252] Exiting WebRequest::Create()    -> FtpWebRequest#28316044
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [27252] FtpWebRequest#28316044::GetRequestStream()
System.Net Information: 0 : [27252] FtpWebRequest#28316044::GetRequestStream(Method=STOR.)
System.Net Information: 0 : [27252] Current OS installation type is 'Client'.
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [27252] ServicePoint#39974954::ServicePoint(1.2.3.4:21)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [27252] Socket#24230272::Socket(AddressFamily#2)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [27252] Exiting Socket#24230272::Socket() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [27252] Socket#16745860::Socket(AddressFamily#23)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [27252] Exiting Socket#16745860::Socket() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [27252] DNS::TryInternalResolve(1.2.3.4)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [27252] Socket#24230272::Connect(1.2.3.4:21#1294145406)
System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [27252] Socket#24230272::UpdateStatusAfterSocketError() - TimedOut
System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [27252] Exception in Socket#24230272::Connect - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 1.2.3.4:21.
System.Net Error: 0 : [27252] Exception in FtpWebRequest#28316044::GetRequestStream - Unable to connect to the remote server.
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [27252] Exiting FtpWebRequest#28316044::GetRequestStream()
```

Comment: Turn Network Tracing on to see what is actually being done, Instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyb3xww8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: How are you running the Release|x86 version outside of visual studio ?

Comment: @user957902 I'm running the Release|x86 by double clicking the .exe file in the bin\x86\Release directory... Enabling Network Tracing now, will let you know what I find.

Comment: @user957902 The trace showed:  System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [9296] Exception in Socket#39974954::Connect - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ----- This doesn't make much sense to me because it works in Debug mode --- Why would it time-out in Release mode?

Comment: Have you tried running a DEBUG|x86 build outside of visual studio ?

Comment: @user957902 Yes I have run the exe directly from bin\x86\Debug and it works fine.

Comment: @user957902 I just ran the Debug version and now it's having the same errors as the Release version --- they both have: Can't retrieve proxy settings for Uri '...'. Error code: 12180. Near the middle of the network trace log - I'll look into this and see if it's related to the timeout.

Comment: Okay, resolved the first issue in the trace regarding proxy settings... I did this by turning off default proxy in config file like this:  
'code' 
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="false" useDefaultCredentials="false">
      <proxy/>
      <bypasslist/>
      <module/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>

Comment: A few obvious things to check. Is the contents of the App.Config the same in the Release and Debug directories ? The trace is showing the correct IP of the target FTP server correct ? If wire shark is showing no packets going out, then assuming the IP layer is working correctly, its probably using the loop-back adapter. Check to make sure that there is nothing weird in your routing table. You can view it with "route PRINT" at the cmd prompt. Also are you on 32bit or 64bit windows OS ?

Comment: @user957902 Good suggestions -- 1. The app.config is identical in Release and Debug. 2. The trace *is* showing the correct IP of the target server. 3. WireShark shows the packets when i execute in VS2013 or manually FTP using WinSCP, but doesn't show any relevant packets when I execute the app from the bin\x86\Release directory. 4. I viewed the routing table using "route PRINT" and it all looks weird to me. 5. I'm using Win 8 64-bit as an OS but building for x86. --- I'm going to try uninstalling BitDefender and see if that makes a difference in the outcome...

Comment: Check settings on your executable VS project. They can be different between debug and release. Is your executable being built explicitly for x86 or ANY_CPU in VS project settings?

Comment: @user957902 Ya I thought about that but Debug and Release are both 32-bit builds.  I uninstalled Bit Defender and all my problems went away. According to our sys admin, it turns out that a firewall is enabled in Bit Defender, but no notification or indication is given to the end-user. It appears it has been blocking *some* apps from communicating through FTP he just doesn't know which ones its set up to block.  Thanks for all your help with me on this - at least I learned about the network Trace capability- Great tool that I will use frequently. Kindest regards, Chuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great suggestion was to use the network trace capability (thanks user957902!) 
However, it was Bitdefender 'endpoint security' managed by the sysadmin that was the culprit. I believe it was some kind of firewall running in stealth mode blocking FTP traffic from some applications (my compiled stuff) and allowing pass-through of others (VS2013). Always look at your security software and question your sys admins when troubleshooting this kind of problem, especially if the traffic works in some cases but not in others - if it doesn't make sense to you, try ruling this type of utility in or out.

regards,
Chuck